# Guest Ubuntu cannot connect to the internet on VirtualBox, bridged

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

I have few VMs with Ubuntu 12.04 nad 12.10 and I'm using them in different networks (at home and at work). At work I'm using wireless connection and at home I have cable.

I'm using bridged mode and ubutnu can't handle it very well, because sometimes VM gets IP address, but I can't ping anything in the internet or even in my local network network. Both cards support bridged mode. Host is Windows 7 64bts. VMs are also 64 bits. Sometimes when I'll reboot VM, everything seems ok.

Any tips?

Edit:

1. I'm starting Ubutnu VM at work and internet connection is working.
   Everything is fine. Bridged adapter is wireless card.
2. I'm going home and launch this same machine, but before that I
   change bridge adapter to my cable network card.
3. VM gets IP address, everything seems ok, besides network is not working. I can't even ping my router and I got IP from it (DHCP).

Comment: Your question is **very** unclear, take your time to tell us a bit more and give us more details about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: See if it works with the virtual network cards configured as NAT instead of bridged

Comment: NAT is working like a charm. There are only problems with bridged mode. It's really weird. I get IP from my router and I see this host on the DHCP client lists on the router, but VM can;t ping that router. It looks like a problem with VBox bridged mode or maybe something with mac. I don't know exactly where should I find any debug/log info.

Answer (score -1):

The question is simple,

Ubuntu 12.10 
Sun Virtual Box can not get network connection if set up to use bridged adaptor.
I have the same issue.  NAT connection work fine.
I need Bridged or go back to ubuntu 10.10 where this all worked...

Thanks

Comment: Nah it's not that. The problem is that in one network I can use bridged mode and in the another one I can't. VM gets ip address properly. I can see that client on my router's website, but I can't  ping anything nor router nor other devices in the same network.